# how to run both validation(emailid,contactno) in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I m performing valiadation(emailid validation,contactno validation)

both are run individually

when I comment code emailaddress validation  then contactno validation work fine

when I comment code contactno validation  then emailaddress validation work fine

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function validatation() {

      //validation for emailaddress
      var emailText = document.getElementById('txtemailid').value;
      var patternemailid = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)*@[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*(\.[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*)*\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
      if (patternemailid.test(emailText)) {
        debugger
        return true;
      } else if ($("#txtemailid").val() == "") {
        alert("Provide a Email Address");
        $("#txtemailid").focus();
        return false;
      } else {
        alert('your Email Address is Bad: ' + emailText);
        debugger
        return false;
      }

      //validation for contactno
      var txtPhone = document.getElementById("txtcontactno").value;
      var phoneno = /^\+?([0-9]{2})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{4})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
      var mobileno = /^((\\+91-?)|0)?[0-9]{10}$/;
      if ((txtPhone.match(phoneno)) || (txtPhone.match(mobileno))) {
        alert("Valid");
      } else {
        alert("Not Valid")
      }
    }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="txtContactInformation" action="displayInfo.html" onsubmit="return validatation()">
    <h1>Contact Information</h1>

    <label for="txtemailid">EmailAddress:</label>
    <input id="txtemailid" name="txtemailid" type="text" /><br/>

    <label for="txtpass">Password:</label>
    <input id="txtpass" name="txtpass" type="password" /><br/>

    <label for="txtcontactno">Contact No:</label>
    <input id="txtcontactno" name="txtcontactno" type="number" /><br/>

    <input id="btnsubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" />

  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to run both validation emailaddress and contactno validation?

Comment: Your email address validation always returns something, exiting the function. You will have a better time if you write separate validateEmail and validatePhone functions that each can return true or false. Your validation function can run like this: `var emailValid = validateEmail(); var phoneValid = validatePhone(); return emailValid && phoneValid;` to check both fields.

Comment: You can just remove the line `return true;`, and then the contactno validation will be working along with emailid validation. As @Charles Bamford said, it better to separate the validations into two methods and call it accordingly.

Comment: @Charles Bamford not working ```onsubmit="return emailValid && phoneValid"``` see below image https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVmcT.png

Comment: If you do as I suggested, you should have three functions for validation. One called validateEmail() that validates email, one called validatePhone() that validates phone numbers, and one called validation() to actually validate the form. You should leave your markup as you had it. The snippet I wrote for you goes in validation().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well your function is not reaching the contact no validation , because you are exiting the funtion after your email validation it self,

you have 2 approcached ,

**1. have different function for email and contact number**

```
        function mailValidation() {

        //validation for emailaddress
        var emailText = document.getElementById('txtemailid').value;
        var patternemailid = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)*@[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*(\.[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*)*\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
        if (patternemailid.test(emailText)) {
            debugger
            return true;
        }
        else if ($("#txtemailid").val() == "") {
            alert("Provide a Email Address");
            $("#txtemailid").focus();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            alert('your Email Address is Bad: ' + emailText);
            debugger
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and

```
function contactNoValidation(){
  //validation for contactno
            var txtPhone = document.getElementById("txtcontactno").value;
            var phoneno = /^\+?([0-9]{2})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{4})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
            var mobileno = /^((\\+91-?)|0)?[0-9]{10}$/;
            if ((txtPhone.match(phoneno)) || (txtPhone.match(mobileno))) {
                alert("Valid");
            }
            else {
                alert("Not Valid")
            }
        }
```

**2. just don't return after email validation and continue further** validation

```
    function validatation() {
        var emailStatus = false;
        var contactNoStatus = false;
        //validation for emailaddress
        var emailText = document.getElementById('txtemailid').value;
        var patternemailid = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)*@[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*(\.[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*)*\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
        if (patternemailid.test(emailText)) {
            debugger
            emailStatus=true;
        }
        else if ($("#txtemailid").val() == "") {
            alert("Provide a Email Address");
            $("#txtemailid").focus();
        }
        else {
            alert('your Email Address is Bad: ' + emailText);
            debugger
        }

        //validation for contactno
        var txtPhone = document.getElementById("txtcontactno").value;
        var phoneno = /^\+?([0-9]{2})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{4})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
        var mobileno = /^((\\+91-?)|0)?[0-9]{10}$/;
        if ((txtPhone.match(phoneno)) || (txtPhone.match(mobileno))) {
            alert("Valid");
        }
        else {
            alert("Not Valid")
        }
        return emailStatus;
    }

       }
```

Comment: I applying 1 first approach but how called both function on submit  button click event that is my main issssue ```onsubmit="return mailValidation && contactNoValidation``` see my code image https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZqD1.png  please help

Comment: A third function will do your job of calling both validation function and it's result is what you use on submit button

Answer (score 0):

a return statement will exit the function so if the compiler finds a return statement, in any case, it will exit the function. So if you want to continue executing the function and do the further validations, remove return statements/

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validatation() {
          
   var Error_description=[];               
            //validation for emailaddress
            var emailText = document.getElementById('txtemailid').value;
            var patternemailid = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)*@[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*(\.[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*)*\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
           
     if (patternemailid.test(emailText)) {
                debugger
                return true;
            }
            else if ($("#txtemailid").val() == "") {
               Error_description.push("Provide a Email Address");           
            }
            else {
                Error_description.push("your Email Address is Bad:"+ emailText);   
            }

            //validation for contactno
            var txtPhone = document.getElementById("txtcontactno").value;
            var phoneno = /^\+?([0-9]{2})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{4})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
            var mobileno = /^((\\+91-?)|0)?[0-9]{10}$/;
            if ((!txtPhone.match(phoneno)) || (!txtPhone.match(mobileno))) {
                Error_description.push("Provide a Valid Phone No");
            }
         
    if(Error_description.length>0){
    alert(Error_description.toString());
    return false;
    }
    else{
    return true;
    }
  
  }
      
   
  
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="txtContactInformation" action="displayInfo.html" onsubmit="return validatation()">
        <h1>Contact Information</h1>

        <label for="txtemailid">EmailAddress:</label>
        <input id="txtemailid" name="txtemailid" type="text" /><br />

        <label for="txtpass">Password:</label>
        <input id="txtpass" name="txtpass" type="password" /><br />

        <label for="txtcontactno">Contact No:</label>
        <input id="txtcontactno" name="txtcontactno" type="number" /><br />

        <input id="btnsubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```